# Your favourite strings plug-in?

Tags: plug-ins, scoring, film

Hi all,

I was wondering what plug-ins would you consider interesting or industry standard to play as MIDI when scoring films with strings. I might use them at some point but my budget is pretty tight!

Thanks

Marco

Comment: Excellent. I'll try them (synful has a demo trial) and post up the results. Cheers Marco

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it works as a plug-in, but I know that most of the short films I mix are scored with Hollywood Strings and LA Strings. That seems to be the standard where I am.

Comment: Heard a ton of great reviews on this plug-in!

Answer (score 1):

I know a few composers who swear by the Vienna Strings libraries - quite expensive but comprehensive...

http://vsl.co.at/

Comment: +1 I've worked with Vienna Strings and they sound great.

Answer (score 0):

Synful Orchestra is a great piece of kit! http://www.synful.com/ recommend it. Might be a bit expensive if you're on a tight budget as you say.

Answer (score -1):

Omnisphere or atmosphere